# Paging Grid displaying all records - Ext JS

Tags: extjs

**EDIT**

It turns out that a store cannot have duplicate IDs. When i remove this field, *All* records display - which means the grid is not respecting the `pageSize`

I'm having an issue getting all my store records to display in my grid. The data is returning appropriately from a JSON request, and the pagingtoolbar behaves correctly.

Here's my store:

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                    storeId     : 'resultsetstore',
                    autoLoad    : false,
                    model       : model,
                    pageSize    : itemsPerPage, // 3
                    proxy: {
                        type    : 'ajaxwithpayload', //custom ajax proxy to read 'jsonData'
                        url     : 'MCApp',
                        jsonData: searchquery,
                        reader: {
                            type    : 'json',
                            root    : 'elements'
                        } 
                    }

});
```

I load the store here, and all the correct results are returned:

```
store.load({ 
                params: { start: 0, limit: itemsPerPage },
                callback : function(records, operation, success) {
                    if(success) {
                        mainresponse = operation.response.responseText;
                        if( mainresponse.length == 0 ){
                            alert('No results returned');
                            return;
                        }
                        var jsonResponse = Ext.JSON.decode(mainresponse);
                    }
                    else {
                        alert('Search Failed: Could not reach the server');
                    }
```

And lastly, a simple grid with `pagingtoolbar`:

```
var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        title: 'Test Data',
        store: store,
        columns: [{
            text: 'Technical Name',
            dataIndex: 'tech'
        }, {
            text: 'ID',
            dataIndex: 'element.id'
        }, {
            text: 'Name',
            dataIndex: 'name',
            mapping: 'element.name'
        }, {
            text: 'View',
            dataIndex: 'view'
        }, {
            text: 'Description',
            dataIndex: 'description'
        }],
       dockedItems: [{
            xtype: 'pagingtoolbar',
            store: store,
            pageSize: itemsPerPage,
            dock: 'bottom',
            displayInfo: true
        }],
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    });
```

The problem here is that not all of my results load into the grid. It seems that when a duplicate ID is encountered, it cuts the results short. That *may not* be the problem, just my guess

In my logs I see all the data I need returned. In the picture below, I should have **3 rows** with the same `Element ID 001`, however only one is displayed:

[image]

Another thing to note is that when I click the Next Button on my pagingtoolbar, the results do not change, and it also reads as a **POST** on my console. I'm not sure if it's supposed to do that or be a **GET**?

I used lightning bolts to show how ***shocking*** it is that this isn't working

Any ideas?

Comment: Duplicated Id is definetely the reason why not all records are diplayed. Fix this before going further.

Comment: I'll have to find a workaround because I have hundreds of records with the same IDs but different associated data, which all need to shown at on the grid.

Comment: Found any workaround? I am facing the same issue. URGENT!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very important thing to note is that the **server** is responsible for paging not ExtJS. The server **must not return all rows**, but only the rows of the **current page**. You server side code must take in account the parameters `page`, `start` and `limit` for getting the client side to work.

I think that, beside the duplicated ids, is the main reason for your problems. It is especially the reason, why you see the same data on page one and on page two:
ExtJs asks the server for the data of page 1 and gets all rows. Later, ExtJs asks the server for the data of page 2 and gets again the same rows. This cannot work.

Comment: Good point Lorenz. I do have `start` and `limit` defined, and I see the params do get passed in my console, I just can't figure out why it's not splitting the records

Comment: It has to be done in your php script. Does your server side code actively support paging ?

Comment: I don't use a php script, my application communicates with a Servlet that pulls data from another application based on a user's search query. I'm not sure if the server side code supports paging, as I did not write it. I assumed ExtJS would take care of the bulk of paging but I suppose I'm incorrect!

Comment: Yes, this is a shortcoming of ExtJs. I was really stuck with it. I chose to use a BufferedRenderer, as I explained in another answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/22401745/1951708). This does not allow for paging, but it allows for infinite scrolling, with all features like local filter, local sort, edit and remote update.

Answer (score 0):

This might be the case when you are giving name property as "id" in the fields array of your Model. try to change that.